# Batch pairs of numbers or exponents

Tags: batch-file, exponent

I'm making a batch program to solve some equations, I'm hoping that my end result can give me the binary for a QR code. Anyway, I just started with the calculations with exponents. **My problem is that I don't know how to do that in batch since I need to use my exponents with a variable x:**

```
x^2 + x^3
x^4 + x^5
x^2 * x^4 + x^3 * x^5 
= x^6 + x^8
```

Then I thought that **I could maybe use couples of numbers since I only need to add one exponent to the other.**

```
(2 , 3) +
(4 , 5)
= (6 , 8)
```

And I searched the web but didn't find anything about it. 
It'd be nice to get help on both methods but (in scratch) I prefer the couples method.

Comment: What is a "batch program"? Do you mean "batch file"? What programming language are you trying to use?

Comment: It is not clear how you intend to pass the input nor how you expect the results to be returned/formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. Your question is not clear; perhaps if you explain us what "binary for a QR code" is we may help you in a better way. Anyway, this is my version of a possible solution.

This program:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=(,) " %%a in (file1.txt) do (
   echo (%%a , %%b^) +
   set /A a+=%%a, b+=%%b
)
echo = (%a% , %b%)
```

... with this data:

```
(2 , 3)
(4 , 5)
```

... produce this output:

```
(2 , 3) +
(4 , 5) +
= (6 , 8)
```

This program:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Do multiplication of all 2-terms equations
for /F "delims=" %%e in (file2.txt) do (
   echo %%e
   set "equation=%%e"
   rem Eliminate "x^ and +" from equation
   for %%a in (x ^^ +) do set equation=!equation:%%a=!
   rem Add exponents
   for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("!equation!") do (
      set /A a+=%%a, b+=%%b
   )
)
echo = x^^%a% + x^^%b%
rem Add similar terms
if %a% equ %b% (
   echo = 2x^^%a%
)
```

... with this data:

```
x^2 + x^3
x^4 + x^5
```

... produce this output:

```
x^2 + x^3
x^4 + x^5
= x^6 + x^8
```

..., but with this data:

```
x^2 + x^3
x^4 + x^3
```

... produce this output:

```
x^2 + x^3
x^4 + x^3
= x^6 + x^6
= 2x^6
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

**There is no operator for exponents in batch arithmetic**. However, it's easy enough to do using multiplication:

```
::x^2
set /a x*=x
::x^3
set /a x*=x*x
::x^4
set /a x*=x*x*x
```

I don't know what you mean by 'couples of numbers', but if you explain I'll try to help.

As a side note, you could use VBScript to do this. For instance, `x = x ^ 2` would square `x`. For more information on VBScript operators, see [here](http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptoperators.php). For information on Batch operators, see [here](http://balamohan.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/batch-operators/).